# Ways to override context-param in web.xml during or after deployment in JBoss AS 6

Tags: jsf, deployment, jboss, web.xml, jboss6.x

In my current JSF 2 project, one setting in the web.xml is

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And its value should be set to `Production` instead `Development` on deployment in JBoss AS.

Are there simple ways to override or modify this web.xml entry during or after deployment?

---

Update: I found [this article](http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/java_app/jboss5/jboss5_web_server.htm) which explains the files in JBoss AS5 `deployers` directory. The author writes:

> There are times when you want a
>   configuration to apply to all web
>   applications, JBoss has global
>   versions of these files which are
>   located in the deployers directory

So for a global-level configuration of web.xml, the file `deployers/jbossweb.deployer/web.xml` can be used. I will check if these files can override values or only add values to the application-level `web.xml`

If you know if `deployers/jbossweb.deployer/web.xml` overrides values in the application level `web.xml`, please leave a message here ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Maven you can do a filtered copy of `web.xml` and set the values from a properties file. Example:

```
<properties>
    <stage.dir>Development</stage.dir>
</properties>
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

And set different values per profile, so you just have to deploy with `mvn goal -P production`. See [properties](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties), [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

Answer (score 0):

As the default value of the `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` parameter is `Production`, I will remove this context-param it from the `web.xml` so it will be `Production` on the live servers, and for the development environment (which is actually a GlassFish v3) I add the context-param to the default web.xml. As application parameters override global parameters, I think this is the most standards based way.